# MySQL select records from one table if their id AND username do not appear in a second table

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables like this:

```
logbook:
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| date_added | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| username   | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| entry      | longtext    | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

and

```
read_logbook:
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| logbook_id | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username   | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What I'd like to do is to select EVERYTHING from `logbook`, but only if the `logbook.id` AND `logbook.username` DO NOT appear in `read_logbook.logbook_id` and `read_logbook.username`, respectively.

I've experimented with some left-union-right queries, as well as some `not in` queries, and keep getting either thousands more results than expected, or no results at all.

Any thoughts?

EDIT - I'd run this for a *specific* username... so basically, if my username was `jmd9qs`, I'd want all results from `logbook` where `read_logbook.id` != `logbook.id` and `read_logbook.username` != `jmd9qs`

I hope that's clear enough...

EDIT - TEST DATA

The logbook:

```
mysql> select id, date_added, username from logbook order by id desc limit 10;
+----+---------------------+-----------+
| id | date_added          | username  |
+----+---------------------+-----------+
| 94 | 2013-09-03 14:54:25 | tluce     |
| 93 | 2013-09-03 13:12:02 | tluce     |
| 92 | 2013-09-03 11:42:14 | tluce     |
| 91 | 2013-09-03 08:28:20 | jmd9qs    |
| 90 | 2013-09-03 07:13:36 | jmd9qs    |
| 89 | 2013-09-03 07:05:19 | jmd9qs    |
| 88 | 2013-09-03 06:57:47 | jsawtelle |
| 87 | 2013-09-03 06:15:42 | jsawtelle |
| 86 | 2013-09-03 05:21:14 | jsawtelle |
| 85 | 2013-09-03 03:52:25 | jsawtelle |
+----+---------------------+-----------+
```

Logbook entries that have been "marked" as read:

```
mysql> select logbook_id, username from read_logbook group by logbook_id desc limit 10;
+------------+----------+
| logbook_id | username |
+------------+----------+
|         94 | jmd9qs   |
|         93 | jmd9qs   |
|         92 | jmd9qs   |
|         91 | jmd9qs   |
|         90 | jmd9qs   |
|         89 | jmd9qs   |
|         88 | jmd9qs   |
|         87 | jmd9qs   |
|         86 | jmd9qs   |
|         85 | jmd9qs   |
+------------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So when I run the query for `jmd9qs`, nothing should come up because in `read_logbook`, his username and the logbook id show up.

CLARIFICATION -

So in the logbook, the username is just the person who wrote `logbook.entry`. In `read_logbook`, username is the person who READ that entry. So if I'm logged in as `jmd9qs`, and I try to view the logbook, since I've read everything no `logbook.entry`'s should come up. But for another user who HASN'T read that specific entry, the entry WOULD show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   logbook 
WHERE  logbook.username NOT IN 
    (SELECT read_logbook.username 
     FROM   read_logbook 
     WHERE  read_logbook.username='jmd9qs')
AND logbook.id NOT IN
    (SELECT read_logbook.logbook_id
     FROM   read_logbook);
```

Comment: It does not. My original question was mega-unclear, I apologize. Please see my numerous edits!

Comment: Saw your updated data. So what do you get when you run: "SELECT * FROM logbook 
WHERE logbook.username NOT IN 
(SELECT read_logbook.username from read_logbook)" ?

Comment: That one seems to work, when I add my username like so: ` SELECT * FROM logbook WHERE logbook.username NOT IN (SELECT read_logbook.username from read_logbook where read_logbook.username='jmd9qs');`

Comment: Update your answer to reflect that and I'll accept it. Thank you, and sorry for being unclear!

Comment: You are doing some GROUP BY in the read_logbook output. This might mess up things....try to do without grouping and then without specifying username.

Comment: I did the group by because I have several duplicate entries, which I will change the code to check for now that I have the right query. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't work :( I still get all entries... there has to be a check for a username AND logbook_id in there somewhere

Comment: I have edited answer. But it should work without specifying username.

Comment: Your edited answer works flawlessly! Thanks a bunch for your help/patience!

Comment: Ok then leave user there. Also I noticed that logbook.id for number 88 is 'jsawtelle' while logbook_id for 88 in the second table is 'jmd9qs'. ids are the same but users are different. Maybe this is the way you want, or not...

Comment: Thanks @Andrew ! This is indeed the way it should be.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your needs, you should try

```
SELECT t1.* FROM logbook t1
LEFT JOIN read_logbook t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.username = t2.username
WHERE t2.id IS NULL AND t2.username IS NULL
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work... I have populated the `read_logbook` with all entries from `logbook`, so when the query runs I should get 0 results. However I realize my question is flawed... please see edit.

Comment: @jmd9qs: I don't see any edit :( Can you please post some test record from both tables and expected result?

Comment: @jmd9qs: with my query, do you get results? Can you show me them?

Comment: Yes, I get too many results... 57 when I should get 0. Hold on for test data in edit...